# Easily navigate from CustomActivity in the designer to CustomActivity class file

Tags: visual-studio, workflow-foundation, designer

If I double click on a CodeActivity step in the Workflow designer, visual studio navigates from the designer to the CodeActivity's handler.

If I double click on my custom Activity in the Workflow designer, nothing happens.

I've added an ActivityDesigner and located the OnMouseDoubleClick... but how do I tell VisualStudio to navigate to a file?  I don't even know what object to start with.